# Can not configure Apolloserver 's datasources in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I am pretty new to TypeScript and Apollo. I'm trying to setup my Apollo server for the first time but I keep getting an error about 'DataSource'. I'm unsure what this means and how to fix it.

```js
import  { ApolloServer, gql } from 'apollo-server';
//...
const { RESTDataSource } = require('apollo-datasource-rest');

class MoviesAPI extends RESTDataSource {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.baseURL = 'https://movies-api.example.com/';
  }

  async getMovie(id) {
    return this.get(`movies/${id}`);
  }

  async getMostViewedMovies(limit = 10) {
    const data = await this.get('movies', {
      per_page: limit,
      order_by: 'most_viewed',
    });
    return data.results;
  }
}


const SERVERCONFIG = {
  'typeDefs': gql(typeDefs) ,
  resolvers,
  dataSources: ()=> ({
      MoviesAPI:  new MoviesAPI(),
  }  ) ,
};

const server = new ApolloServer(SERVERCONFIG);
```

I get the following error:

```
Type '{ 'typeDefs': DocumentNode; resolvers: { Query: {}; }; dataSources: () => { MoviesAPI: MoviesAPI; }; }' is not assignable to type 'ApolloServerExpressConfig'.
    The types returned by 'dataSources()' are incompatible between these types.
      Type '{ MoviesAPI: MoviesAPI; }' is not assignable to type 'DataSources<object>'.
        Property 'MoviesAPI' is incompatible with index signature.
          Type 'MoviesAPI' has no properties in common with type 'DataSource<object>'.
```

I can get the error to go away if I did something like:   dataSources: ()=> ({...MoviesAPI}) but I do not think that fixes the problem...

Does anyone know what is causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
const { RESTDataSource } = require('apollo-datasource-rest');
```

to

```
import { RESTDataSource } from 'apollo-datasource-rest';
```

This should fix it for you.